# How to detect browser (not window) close event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to detect browser close (not the window(tab)) and run a script. I tried `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` but they are working fine with tab close but if I close entire browser nothing happens. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I just want to do a server side cleanup on any these kind of event. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: That would, I think, require JavaScript to have access to the browser's chrome; which I don't think is possible (nor, if I'm honest, would I *want* it to be), and certainly not a good security feature. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: You can't. Why would a browser allow a website to know of that (and maybe even prevent it)?

Comment: I want to do a server side cleanup for any this kind of event. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: No way. You can't force a browser to send a server request on closing - also, the browser/computer may just crash. The only reliable way to do such is using a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question as asked, 'how can I [access the browser-close event]?' the only possible answer is: you can't; it's not possible. Nor, for security reasons, should it be.

> I want to do a server side cleanup for any this kind of event. Is there any possible way to do it?

The only way I could think of, with JavaScript, is trigger an Ajax call to a server-side script notifying it of the close-event, using `onunload` or `onbeforeunload`, and having that script tidy up any sessions that might still be open.

Comment: Yeah I tried using onunload and onbeforeunload to call using Ajax. It is working on tab close, but not for Browser close.

Comment: Yes, but that's the point: JavaScript has no access to the browser-close event. And why does it need to be 'browser-close' rather than the window-, or tab-, close event?

Comment: I have those events also. But for extra protection I need to run a cleanup on browser close also.